# DocuSign ListRecipients() not working, but other calls OK

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the Docusign eSign API for an integration.  My integration key works fine with building and sending envelopes, and with checking envelope status (using GetEnvelope()).  But ListRecipients() doesn't work.     I have been following the documentation from here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-recipients/.

My recipient-checking code is:

```
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken.access_token.ToString()); // I am suspicious of this line

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

foreach (var envelope in envelopes)
{
    List<SignerModel> listSigners = new List<SignerModel>();
    Recipients results = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(_apiAccountId, envelope.envelopeId.ToString());
    // Do something with it...
}
```

When I run this with the suspicious line in place (un-commented) I get this error message at that line:

> GetSigners error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I comment it out I get the same error message at the ListRecipients() call.

This is how I am getting my access token:

```
                List<string> docusignScopes = new List<string> { "impersonation", "signature" };
           
                apiClient = new ApiClient(_restBasePath);
                authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                    _clientId,
                    _impersonatedUserId,
                    _authServer,
                    privateKeyBytes, 1, docusignScopes);
```

Why is the listRecipients call not working?

Comment: Can you get the full StackTrace? I run envelopesApi.ListRecipients() and it worked just fine....

Comment: Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't show anything useful.  It simply shows which line the breakpoint is at.

Comment: Can you have a code with only these lines and see if that works:

Comment: see my answer for the code that works:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code and it works just fine. Make sure to put your envelopeID in there. Try this basic code and let me know:

```
    var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
    var rec = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(accountId, "4f925c10-xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx");
```

Comment: Marking this as the selected answer because it triggered me to look at my code again.  The issue was that I needed to initialize the apiClient again.  In my code I did this much earlier but it turns out apiClient was out of scope.  By adding the initialization in before this area it works fine.  I already had the envelope ID in there, so that was fine.